# Redirect domain and sub pages with 301 to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect `test777.website.com` and all the pages inside it such as  `test77.website.com/blog` and `test777.website.com/contact-us` to `website.com` with 301 redirects.

I tried to do it with HTACCESS but wasnt successful. Can you please tell me the proper way to do this so google knows its not a 500 or 404 but a 301. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test777\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules into the http servers host configuration instead of relying on dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Reason is that those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server, often for nothing. The mechanism to use such files is only provided as a last option for situations where you do *not* have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting providers) and for applications that insist on writing their own redirection rules (which is an obvious security nightmare...).

Comment: OMG thanks so much. It works perfectly well. And it recirect to the proper page as well which is something I thought was not possible. MMmmmah mmmah!